# Fetch after Fetch and waiting for res, second end point get empty req

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

i try to create a profile, that the imageid is saved inside the database, untill now all the code work good, the image upload work, and res good, and save the files.

but when i try to create a profile alawys the data i get to the createProfile Api
is undefined and cant be reached.

i have tried to use bodyParser,
json.stringtfy as in the code.

the other API work good. just when i try to use fetch inside fetch or pass with axios it alawys reach empty

this my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form id="createProfile" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <p>profile name:</p>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
                <p>image</p>
                <input type="file" name="image">
                <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
</body>

</html>
```

this my js:

```
    const form = document.getElementById('createProfile')
    const name = document.getElementById('name')
    form.addEventListener('submit', async e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      const data = new FormData(form)

      console.log(...data)

      try {
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/uploadimage', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: data
        })

        const resData = await res.json()
        console.log(resData)

        if (resData.code === 200) {
          const resProfile = await fetch(
            'http://localhost:4000/api/createProfile',
            {
              method: 'POST',
              body: JSON.stringify({
                name: name.value,
                imageid: resData.imageid
              })
            }
          )
          const resProfileData = await resProfile.json()

          console.log(resProfileData.profileid + 'has been created')
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message)
      }
    })
  }
```

my end point of uploadimage:

```
exports.uploadimage = async function(req,res){

  if (req.file) {
    var imgsrc = './images/' + req.file.filename
    var insertData = "INSERT INTO images(image)VALUES(?)"

    connection.query(insertData,[imgsrc], (err,result)=>{
      if(err) throw err
      console.log("file uploaded")
      console.log(result.insertId);
      res.status(200).json({
        code:200,
        imageid:result.insertId,
        success:'image saved successfully'
      })

    } )
  } else {
    res.status(400).send("Please upload a valid image");
  }

}
```

my create profile end point:

```
exports.createProfile = async function ( req, res) {
  try {
    const requestedData = req.body;
    console.log(requestedData.name);
        
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
}
```

i have tried to use bodyParser,
json.stringtfy as in the code, use cors().

the other API work good. just when i try to use fetch inside fetch or pass with axios it always reach empty.

i just want to be able to get the request with data, and ill deal the rest.

thank you everyone for help.

Comment: With the details you show right now, it is hard to debug. Besides that, you should simplify your search for the problem. That the one `fetch` follows the other is not the problem. So create a function that does the `await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/createProfile',` with some static data and call that directly. Check what the browser sends as a request in the network tab of the developer console. (Does it contain the data? What content type is used for the request part?). And you don't show how you tried to use `bodyParser`.

Comment: Uh, your `createProfile` endpoint never writes a response?

Comment: @t.niese has a great point. Split them into separate functions and you can test them separately.

Answer (score 0):

I like the more "convoluted" structure using callback functions and `then()`. Does it change anything if you add the header `Content-Type` to the second request? In the first request the content type is `multipart/form-data` now that you set the body to be a formData object. In the second request the backend does not know the content type and therefore the `res.body` doesn't contain anything.

Assuming that the API works, I replaced the endpoint URLs with data URIs, so that you can see that the code works.

```js
document.forms.createProfile.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = e.target;
  const data = new FormData(form);

  fetch('data:aplication/json,{"code":200,"imageid":1234}', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
  }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
    if (data.code === 200) {
      fetch('data:aplication/json,{"profileid":"12345","code":200}', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: {
          name: form.name.value,
          imageid: data.imageid
        }
      }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
        console.log(data.profileid, 'has been created')
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form name="createProfile" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>profile name:</p>
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <p>image</p>
  <input type="file" name="image">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: How does this "answer" solve the problem or at least tell where the problem might be? The OP has the problem that the server-side code receives a request, but that the `req.body` does not contain any data.

Comment: @t.niese good point :-) I updated my answer with an explanation -- and hopefully with a real solution to the problem.